# Does Nextcloud installation gives passwordless access to all files by default?

Tags: authentication, webserver, access-control

I used [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nextcloud-on-debian-10-buster-linux) to install Nextcloud instance on a Raspberry Pi. The installation went smoothly and in the end I could open the Nextcloud login page which, once presented with the right password, gives access to various resources which I assumed were therefore password-protected. That is, until I tried to log out and type `https://server/nextcloud/data/user/files/`, which, to my surprise, showed a directory listing of Nextcloud files belonging to `user`, without requiring a password at all!

Is Nextcloud really missing any data protection whatsoever in its right-out-of-the-box state, or did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with Nextcloud, but rather with the random guy's installation guide that you chose to follow. Had you followed [Nextcloud's official one](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/admin_manual/installation/index.html) instead, then that attack wouldn't work. The problem is that Nextcloud uses a .htaccess file to protect that directory, and the random unofficial installation guide didn't bother to tell you that you needed to enable .htaccess files in Apache's config (`AllowOverride`). This mistake is common enough that under "Security & setup warnings" under Administration -> Overview, it will self-test and warn you about it if it detects it.

Further, following Nextcloud's hardening and security guidance would also stop this, as they recommend that you [set the data directory to be somewhere that's not under the document root](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/admin_manual/installation/harden_server.html#place-data-directory-outside-of-the-web-root).

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Good thing I checked this before I really started using it.